# How to show and hide the data when the condition is true

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular, typescript

In my angular application I have created the dashboard page. In that page I have created some conditions based on the condition it has to show on the view if the condition is false it will remove from the view page.

**Dashboard.component.ts**

```
var insidecirclespace1 = (lat,long) => {
for (var i=0; i< this.sensors.length;i++){

  if (getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(this.sensors[i].latitude, this.sensors[i].longitude, lat,long) <= 5.0) {
    circlemark[i].setStyle({ color: 'red', weight: 1, opacity: 7.0 });
    
      "model": "1001",
      "sensorname": "Sensor 1",
     
     "rf": "1",
      "Idref": "1"
    });

  }
  
  }
  outsidespace(latlngs[latlngidx1].lat,latlngs[latlngidx1].lon,latlngs02[latlngidx2].lat,latlngs02[latlngidx2].lon);

}

var insidecirclespace2 = (lat,long) => {
  for (var i=0; i< this.sensors.length;i++){
  
    if (getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(this.sensors[i].latitude, this.sensors[i].longitude, lat,long) <= 5.0) {
      circlemark[i].setStyle({ color: 'red', weight: 1, opacity: 7.0 });

      this.wifiDrones.push({
       
        "model": "1002",
        "sensorname": "Sensor 2",
        "rf": "1",
        "Idref": "1"
      });
 }
     
    }

    outsidespace(latlngs[latlngidx1].lat,latlngs[latlngidx1].lon,latlngs02[latlngidx2].lat,latlngs02[latlngidx2].lon);
   }

  var outsidespace = (lat1,long1,lat2,long2)=>{

    for (var i=0; i< this.sensors.length;i++){
  
      if (getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(this.sensors[i].latitude, this.sensors[i].longitude, lat1,long1) > 5.0 && getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(this.sensors[i].latitude, this.sensors[i].longitude, lat2,long2) > 5.0) {
        circlemark[i].setStyle({ color: 'blue', weight: 1, opacity: 7.0 });
      
        }
}
    
    }
```

Based on the above condition the html page will show as

**.component.html**

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
  
                    <h5 class="card-text " style="color: white;"> {{x.model}}
                    </h5>

<!--some code -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Now my requirement is if the getdistanceInKm is less than 5 km It has to show the data on html page view if the distance is more than 5 km it has to remove (It will continuous for moving marker  <5km or >5km)

It is coming for <5km for removing in >5km is not working can anyone please help me regarding this.

Comment: getdistanceInKm is a function or propery ? Since you can use it in *ngIf within the HTML Element you want to view

Comment: function I have created

Comment: @yazan Can you help me for the above code

Comment: Answer Posted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *ngIf will do the trick, you can use by providing your function inside the *ngIf or any property as follows:

1. using a propery:

in your ts file you could create a property for e.g. distance:

```
distance: number = 0;
```

and update your distance propery in your functions and using binding you could show and hide your HTML element as follows:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="distance < 5">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-text " style="color: white;"> {{x.model}}
         </h5>
    <!--some code -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

2. using a function, if the getdistanceInKm function will return a number this will do the job also:

   ```
   <div class="col-sm-4" *ngIf="getdistanceInKm()< 5">
   <div class="card-body">
   <!--some code -->
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

**Updated**
Also you can use ViewChild as follows for changing the HTML element from ts file:

HTML file:

```
<div #distanceElement class="col-sm-4">
<div class="card-body">
<!--some code -->
  </div>
</div>
```

ts file:

```
@ViewChild('distanceElement ') el:ElementRef;
```

and when changes occurs you can use:

```
 this.el.nativeElement.style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div  *ngIf="validation()">
 <h5 class="card-text " style="color: white;"> {{x.model}}</h5>
</div>
```

.TS

```
validation() {
       // logic if less than 5 km return 
     return true;
      }
```

P.s This is just an overview, the syntax or the approach may not be perfect

Comment: Can you please provide the appropriate code for my above code and getdistanceinKm is a function I have created